# Failed to load module script in angular ssr

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering

I am trying to load one of my angular components but whenever I access the component in my Chrome browser, I get an error: `Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.` This issue is only occurring in my local environment and works fine in our dev environment.I wanted to try and solve this issue by running `ng build --prod --base-href yoursubfolder` but I am using angular v8 ssr to build and deploy my application (`npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr`). How can I resolve this issue in angular ssr?

Comment: You want to pass the `baseHref` through `npm run`? Have you tried `npm run build:ssr -- --prod --base-href yoursubfolder`? The `-- --` means that all upcoming parameters are passed not to `npm run` but to `build:ssr` instead.

Comment: I get `Unknown option: '--prod'` and `Unknown option: '--base-href'` error when running that command with my subfolder

Comment: Oh yeah prod is deprecated, use `--configuration production` instead. and you can also set the base-href in `angular.json` (`yourapp:architect:build:options:baseHref` = `/yoursubfolder/`)